# What happens if I don't cancel a Context?

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
func Call(ctx context.Context, payload Payload) (Response, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(...) // Some code that creates request from payload
    ctx, cancel = context.withTimeout(ctx, time.Duration(3) * time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    return http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
}
```

What would happen if I didn't put `defer cancel()` in there?  `go vet` warns about it:

> the cancel function returned by context.WithTimeout should be called, not discarded, to avoid a context leak

How will the context be leaked and what impact will this have?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you fail to cancel the context, the [goroutine that WithCancel or WithTimeout created](https://golang.org/src/context/context.go?s=9162:9288) will be retained in memory indefinitely (until the program shuts down), causing a memory leak.  If you do this a lot, your memory will balloon significantly.  It's best practice to use a `defer cancel()` immediately after calling `WithCancel()` or `WithTimeout()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true anymore? I did some tests, the goroutine will be normally released. It's not the goroutine that being leaked but the child context. Without canceling the context, all child contexts will remain in memory until the parent context is canceled. https://play.golang.org/p/8lJ7nQOj45Y

Answer (score 31):

If you use `WithCancel`, the *goroutine* will be held indefinitely in memory. However, if you use `WithDeadline` or `WithTimeout` without calling cancel, the *goroutine* will only be held until the timer expires.

This is still not best practice though, it's always best to call `cancel` as soon as you're done with the resource.