# Conditionally close a keep-alive http connection

Tags: go

I created an http client using following code:

```golang
httpClient := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns:        50,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 5,
        DisableKeepAlives: false,
    },
}
```

By default, I want to reuse all http connections (`Connection: Keep-Alive`).
However, I want to cancel a specific underlying http connection manually, whenever the response status code is `500`.

I found that `Transport.CanceRequest` can help me achieve this goal exactly. However, it is deprecated and it does not support HTTP/2.

```golang
// CancelRequest cancels an in-flight request by closing its connection.
// CancelRequest should only be called after RoundTrip has returned.
//
// Deprecated: Use Request.WithContext to create a request with a
// cancelable context instead. CancelRequest cannot cancel HTTP/2
// requests.
func (t *Transport) CancelRequest(req *Request) {
    t.cancelRequest(cancelKey{req}, errRequestCanceled)
}
```

Then I used `context.Context` to cancel a http connection manually.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", "http://www.yahoo.co.jp", nil)
resp, _ = myHttpClient.Do(req)
if (resp.StatusCode == 500) {
     cancel() // Cancel the underline HTTP connection because I don't want to re-use it.
     return;
}
// Do not call cancel() anymore because I can to re-use it later.
```

For the above code, there is a warning says:

> the cancel function is not used on all paths (possible context leak)

**The problem is that, If I use `defer cancel()` then all the connections can't be reused. But if I don't call `defer cancel()`, then [there might memory leak without canceling context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393995/what-happens-if-i-dont-cancel-a-context).**

How can I resolve this issue?

I searched the whole Internet but I couldn't find a solution. It seems that no one has the need of re-using an http connection when using context.

Comment: "If I use defer cancel() then all the connections can't be reused." That's not true. Cancelling the  request context does not affect the underlying connection. You cannot arbitrarily close a connection if HTTP2 is a concern, because any number if requests can be in flight on a single connection at any given time (the main selling point of HTTP2).

Comment: @Peter Without thinking about HTTP2. Then the only solution is that I stick to use the deprecated method `Transport.CancelRequest()`? Why the golang source code suggests me to use `Request.WithContext` if it cannot cancel the underlying connection?

Comment: CancelRequest predates contexts (at least it wasn't in the standard library back then). Closing the connection worked to cancel requests, but as the name sugests the intend was always to cancel the _request_, not the _connection_. You can probably use [Hijack](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Hijacker) if you don't care about HTTP2.